# how to slide tableview to right when editing

Tags: ios, uitableview

What I want is when I am editing the tableview.

Such as deleting. When I am in deleting mode and the tableview will animate to slide to right so that looks more beautiful.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314284/animate-uitableviewcell-contentview-to-fade-upon-entering-edit-mode

Comment: No.My key is to add all the subviews to self.contentview but not self.